# Laravel 5: Controller Testing - PHPUnit returns green

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, testing

the following simple controller test makes a 'GET' request to the PostsController@index action:

```
<?php 

class PostsControllerTest extends TestCase {

    public function testIndex()
    {
        $response = $this->action('GET', 'PostsController@index');

    }
}
```

In my understanding, if the index method does not exist in my controller, I shouldn't get the green light, when calling **phpunit** in my command line.

Yet my controller looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    // public function index()
    // {
    //    //
    //    return 'Posts Index';
    //}
}
```

As you can clearly see the index method is commented out and I still get this:

```
**OK (1 test, 0 assertions)**
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't making any assertions. Your test isn't checking if `$response` is "OK".

Change your test to this:

```php
public function testIndex()
{
    $response = $this->action('GET', 'PostsController@index');
    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());
}
```

This test asserts that the page responded with a [200 status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success), which means it was successful.

You can read up on Laravel's testing [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#application-testing).